# Supress time messages in Vivado simulator

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I am working with Vivado simulator.

I would like to know if it is possible to suppress the time messages in the Tcl console. They are printed with the note entry:

```
report "LED1 is turned on" severity note;
```

results int:

> Note: LED1 is turned on
>   Time: 4477500 ps  Iteration: 6  Process: /testbench/\GEN(1)/line__280  File: H:/Image/Image.srcs/sim_1/new/tb.vhd

Can I get rid of this time entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the report and assert format is fixed.

But, you can write to STDOUT from VHDL. These messages are displayed without time information in the simulator console (between other messages).

**Example for writing to STDOUT:**

```
use   STD.TextIO.all;

procedure test is
  variable LineBuffer : LINE;
begin
  write(LineBuffer, "test message");
  writeline(output, LineBuffer);
end procedure;
```

Source: https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/sim/sim_protected.v08.vhdl#L150-L226

**Screenshot from iSim:**

[image]

*The output from Vivado Simulator should be similar.*

Answer (score 2):

Thank you so for this post it really helped me.

It is not straight forward though.

You need to mark them as a string unfortunately. So in vivado the following will work

```
use   STD.TextIO.all;

procedure test is
   variable LineBuffer : LINE;
begin
   write(LineBuffer, string'("test message"));
   writeline(output, LineBuffer);
end procedure;
```

Please note its not in brackets its with an apostrophe.